# determine which default namenode and namenode_port "hadoop fs -ls" is using

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running the below command:

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

I know that this command really corresponds to something like the below:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://<namenode>:<namenode_port>
```

How do I determine these values of `namenode` and `namenode_port`?

I've already tried examining environment variables and looking at the documentation, but I couldn't find anything to do exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer hadoop configuration file `core-site.xml` for `<namenode>` and `<namenode_port>` values. Search for configuration property `fs.defaultFS`(latest) or `fs.default.name`(depricated).

core-site.xml file can be located in `/etc/hadoop/conf` or `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/conf` locations.

**Edit** 
There is a dynamic way to do this. Below hadoop command will give HDFS URI. 

`hdfs getconf -confKey "fs.defaultFS"`

However, every time hadoop commands get executed, hadoop loads client configurations xml files. If you wanted to test this out, create a separate client configurations in some other directories by copying contents of /etc/hadoop/conf to new directory( let's say /home//hadoop-conf, it should contain core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml), override the environment variable using the command `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/<USER>/hadoop-conf`, update core-site.xml files, then test using hadoop command. Remember this is only for testing purpose, unset the environment variable ( `unset HADOOP_CONF_DIR`) once you are done with your testing.

Comment: thanks, but is there any dynamic way to do this? or does the hadoop fs command read this xml file every time it makes a call?